# update failure in CentOS

Tags: centos

I am using CentOS 6.4 .while I am doing package updating i am getting these errors.

```
  file /usr/lib/libpostproc.so.52 conflicts between attempted installs of ffmpeg-libs-0.10.7-1.el6.i686 and ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.i686
  file /usr/lib/libswresample.so.0 conflicts between attempted installs of ffmpeg-libs-0.10.7-1.el6.i686 and ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.i686
  file /usr/lib/libswscale.so.2 conflicts between attempted installs of ffmpeg-libs-0.10.7-1.el6.i686 and ffmpeg-libs_1.1-1.1.5-2.el6.i686
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mattdm's answer is probably the way to go but if you want to you could try excluding those packages from being evaluated as part of the upgrade.

```
$ sudo yum -x ffmpeg-libs upgrade
```

From the `yum` man page:

```
-x, --exclude=package
      Exclude a specific package by name or glob from updates on all 
      repositories.  Configuration Option: exclude
```

#### The power of disablerepo & enablerepo

One of the less obvious things you can do with `yum` is play games with these to "dynamically" enable and disable various repos when running commands. To see it's effect I like to use yum's `repolist` command.

Example:

```
$ yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=*fusion-free-up* repolist|awk '{print $1}'|sed '1,3d;$d'
rpmfusion-free-updates
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo
rpmfusion-free-updates-source
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-debuginfo
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-source
```

Or you can purely disable multiple repos:

```
$ yum --disablerepo=*fusion* --disablerepo=*adobe* repolist|awk '{print $1}'|sed '1,3d;$d'
Dropbox
fedora
google-chrome
google-earth
google-talkplugin
lamolabs
lamolabs-noarch
nautilus-flickr-uploader
scootersoftware
updates
wuala
```

#### VLC Repositories?

In CentOS 6.x I'd be using the following repos to make use of VLC.

```
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
```

Update to the latest VLC:

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-test update vlc
```

#### References

- [yum man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)

Comment: please see this http://pastebin.com/VJ3rFWPN\

Comment: Run the command with this: `--disablerepo=*fusion*`. This will temp. disable all the fusion repos.

Comment: did you mean to run ` yum -y --disablerepo=*fusion* upgrade ` ?

Comment: @rajagenupula - yup.

Comment: its running updating now. hope its solved but will i able to get future updates for VLC ?

Comment: @rajagenupula - If the upgrade works, you can try just an update for the vlc package (`yum update vlc`) or whatever packages are coming from RPMFusion. Or you can play the same trick and disable all repos and then enable just rpmfusion, ala (`yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=*fusion-free-up* update vlc`).

Comment: No I am getting the same conflict error , update of other pkgs are successful but yum -y update vlc gave me conflict error

Comment: @rajagenupula - did you disable all the other repos and enable only rpmfusion?

Comment: No I have just done yum update  vlc

Comment: yeah I have tried with disabling all repos except the fusion and then again got the conflict error

Answer (score 1):

These packages aren't part of CentOS itself; I expect you got them from RPMFusion or another add-on repository.

The easiest approach is to temporarily remove the offending packages, do your upgrades, make sure your RPMFusion configuration is up-to-date, and then reinstall what you need.

Comment: please see this http://pastebin.com/VJ3rFWPN

Comment: @rajagenupula Yep. Seriously, `yum remove vlc-core`, and then put it back after upgrade.